# SVG in Chrome, <tspan> x and y values are ignored

Tags: html, google-chrome, browser, svg

In Firefox and IE, the following SVG code works, it draws each character of the word EXAMPLE at an x coordinate listed in the `<tspan> x` attribute, and all characters at the y coordinate.

```
<text style="font-size: 183px ; fill:rgb( 0 , 0 , 0 ); font-family: Trebuchet MS"> 
    <tspan x="1575 1716 1857 1998 2139 2280 2421" y="212">EXAMPLE</tspan>     
</text>
```

According to [w3.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/text.html#TSpanElement) this is fine in both SVG 1.1 and 1.0.

However, in Chrome these values are being ignored and they are drawn all the way up in the top left of the viewbox. If I copy the x and y values into the `<text>` tag then it works in Chrome (FF and IE too).

```
<text style="font-size: 183px ; fill:rgb( 0 , 0 , 0 ); font-family: Trebuchet MS"
 x="1575 1716 1857 1998 2139 2280 2421" y="212"> 
    <tspan>EXAMPLE</tspan>     
</text>
```

As the file I'm working with is automatically generated from a program, it's not quite so easy for me to make that change.

Why is Chrome ignoring these elements? Is making changes to the program my only option here?

Comment: Have you reported this bug at http://crbug.com?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `dx` and `dy` instead, you can find info on how to use them here: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/svg/tspan-element.html